# formatting post data before post in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http-post

how do i send my `cartPost` post data as :

```
products=
[
   {
    "code": "mig-09",
    "title": "supermig",
    "quantity": "1"
   }
]
```

here is my `http.post`

```
$http.post("www.remoteurl.com", {
    products: cartPost
}).success(function(data){
  $scope.cart = data;
})
```

i need to do like that, because in server side. The post data will be populated in `$products = json_decode($_POST['products'])` otherwise it wont work. How do i do it? can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is cartPost an array?

Comment: cartPost is contain with `[
   {
    "code": "mig-09",
    "title": "supermig",
    "quantity": "1"
   }
]`

Comment: Does only sending it work? $http.post("www.remoteurl.com", cartPost)

Comment: no, the post data must be like this `products=[{"code":"mig-09"}]` only that it will work

Comment: That's not valid JSON

Comment: not clear what your issue is. Have you tried using `file_get_contents('php://input')` to access body of post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'www.remoteurl.com',
    data:'products=' + cartPost, // the solution
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
.success(function(response) {
    $scope.result = response;
});
```